# How to remove all alphabetic items from a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

This is my code:

```
filter_list=[1,2,'a','b']
import re
ne=[]
for i in filter_list:
    m=re.search(r"[a-zA-Z]",i)
    if m:
        ne.append(m.group())
print(ne)
```

Expected Output:

```
ne=[1,2]
```

But I'm getting this error:
`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: You're trying to perform a regex search on an int. That does not make sense.

Comment: Do you have non-alphabetic strings on the list, e.g., "123"? What about mixed strings "abc123"? Should they be removed or kept? In any case, the problem does not require `re`.

Answer (score 3):

Given what you have, I believe what you are trying to do is:

```
filter_list = [1,2,'a','b']
import re
ne = []
for i in filter_list:
    m = re.search(r"[0-9]+",str(i))
    if m:
        ne.append(int(m.group()))
print(ne)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

---

But I'd suggest an alternative:

```
filter_list = [1,2,'a','b']
ne = [i for i in filter_list if isinstance(i, int)]

print(ne)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

Comment: Hey Ann it got stuck for this input
filter_list = [1,'a','b',0,15]
expected=[1,0,15]

Answer (score 1):

cast your variable (integers) into string before passing into regex.

```
m = re.search(r"[a-zA-Z]", str(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

That because the second parameter of `re.search` must be a string or a bytes-like object and in your case it is an integer. Perhaps your list should have been:

```
filter_list = ['1', '2', 'a', 'b']
```

Note that if you intend to remove all alphabetic items you could also do:

```
list(filter(lambda x: not x.isalpha(), filter_list)) # Return not alphabetic items ["1", "2"]
```

Or

```
list(filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), filter_list)) # Return alphabetic items ["a", "b"]
```

Also, if you use itertools you could do:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.filterfalse(str.isalpha, filter_list))
```

Comment: `list(filter(lambda))` is ugly. Use a comprehension instead: `[x for x in filter_list if not x.isalpha()]`

Comment: Well you usually would just leave it as an iterator, in which case the filter would be beautiful, since I guessed he will print it afterwards and he would like to see the results, I added the list()

Comment: Here is an iterator : `(x for x in filter_list if not x.isalpha())`.

Comment: @DYZ And don't you think `itertools.filterfalse(str.isalpha, filter_list)` is more readable?

Comment: Not to me. But it's opinion based. I just say that a list comprehension can be an iterator.

Comment: And you are correct, I mentioned the iterator since @wjandrea didn't like the `list(filter())`, and he is right in case you need the list. In my opinion the usage of `filter()` in cases you can accept iterator is pretty, and I guess you would agree with me it is at least not ugly :)

Answer (score 1):

In your case you used int in the regex which led to the error.

Other than that a better function in regex would be the [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

If you want to remove the alpabethical items from the list and the list has a mix of types I would do it this way.

```
import re  
def filter(lst):
    return [re.sub(r"[a-zA-Z]", '', item) if(type(item) == str) else item for item in lst ]
```